# readLine() null return

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    File file = new File("C:\\New\\r.txt");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while(in.readLine() != null) {      
        sb.append(in.readLine());
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
    s = sb.toString();
    byte[] b = s.getBytes();

   for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
       if(b[i] == 1){ b[i]=0; }
       if(b[i] == 0){ b[i]=1; }
   }

   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
   DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
   dos.write(b);
   in.close();
   fos.close();
   dos.close();
}
```

I get a return of null when I run this program. Maybe I must elevate the program? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This program does not 'return' anything. Add the stacktrace to your question. Also, why are you flipping all the bytes in your input file to a '1' value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
 while(in.readLine()!=null)
```

to:

```
 while((s = in.readLine())!=null)
```

and then:

```
sb.append(s);
```

When you call in your code to `in.readLine()` twice - you're reading two lines but printing only the second in each iteration.

Comment: i suspect that `s` is  string . so how the while checks without boolean type i may be wrong .@alfasin

Comment: @ATR `s = in.readLine()` is an assignment and the `!= null` is the expression that returns a boolean

Comment: @MohammodHossain I forgot a pair of brackets - corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing away every odd line:

```
while(in.readLine()!=null)
{      
   sb.append(in.readLine());
}
```

If `r.txt` only contains one line, you will get the string "null" in the `StringBuffer`, because the first line of `StringBuffer.append` does this:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
  if (str == null) str = "null";
  ....
}
```

If there are two lines, you will get the first line with "null" at the end of the line.

The following will append all lines from the file to the `StringBuffer`:

```
String line = null;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{      
   sb.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
while(in.readLine() != null) {      
        sb.append(in.readLine());
    }
```

change with it

```
  while ((s = in.readLine()) != null)
 {               
    sb.append(s);

 }
```